# I want the data in 'data frame' the code is working perfectly

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want the data in 'data frame' the code is working perfectly please solve these issue and provide data in Data Frame I try to solve it but faliure to do these

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import time
        
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('F:\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action")
    
    headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"}
    
    for title in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('option'):
        title.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("iframe")[1])
        table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table table")
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "lxml")
        all_data = []
        ratings = {"BUY":[], "HOLD":[], "SELL":[]}
        lists_ = []
        for row in soup.select("tr")[-4:-1]:
            info_list = row.select("td")
            count = info_list[1].text
            percent = info_list[2].text
            
            IBServ_count = info_list[4].text
            IBServ_percent = info_list[5].text
            
            lists_.append([count, percent, IBServ_count, IBServ_percent])
            
        ratings["BUY"] = lists_[0]
        ratings["HOLD"] = lists_[1]
        ratings["SELL"] = lists_[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np
    
browser = webdriver.Chrome('F:\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action")

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"}

title_lists = []
buy_lists = []
hold_lists = []
sell_lists = []

for title in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('option'):
    title.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    title_lists.append(title.text)
    browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("iframe")[1])
    table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table table")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "lxml")
    lists_ = []
    for row in soup.select("tr")[-4:-1]:
        info_list = row.select("td")
        count = info_list[1].text
        percent = info_list[2].text
        
        IBServ_count = info_list[4].text
        IBServ_percent = info_list[5].text
        
        lists_.append([count, percent, IBServ_count, IBServ_percent])
    buy_lists.append(lists_[0])
    hold_lists.append(lists_[1])
    sell_lists.append(lists_[2])
    browser.switch_to.default_content()

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['BUY','HOLD', 'SELL'],
                                     ['Count','Percent','IBServ_count', 'IBServ_percent']],names=['Action','Rating'])

m = np.array([[i[0] for i in buy_lists], [i[1] for i in buy_lists], [i[2] for i in buy_lists], [i[3] for i in buy_lists], 
             [i[0] for i in hold_lists], [i[1] for i in hold_lists], [i[2] for i in hold_lists], [i[3] for i in hold_lists],
             [i[0] for i in sell_lists], [i[1] for i in sell_lists], [i[2] for i in sell_lists], [i[3] for i in sell_lists]])
dc = pd.DataFrame(np.rot90(m),columns = header)
dc["Title"] = title_lists
dc = dc.set_index("Title")
dc.to_csv('out.csv', index = 0)
```

I used `numpy` to manipulate the array of information I created. It may not be the best usage of `pandas` but it creates the `DataFrame` you are looking for.

Comment: It will run but not provide `CSV file`

Comment: Add ```dc.to_csv('out.csv', index = 0)``` to the end.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: the code is running but not provide `csv file `

Comment: they show theses `Running] python -u "e:\CaptainCazRepo\src\up.py"` for 10 minute but not provide `csv file`

Comment: yes I add the line

Comment: running in `visual studio code`

Comment: Does your program finish executing? Or does it just get stuck? Do you get any kind of error? Can you restart the Visual Studio and try again? Can you print out the dataframe? This program works for me. It's so hard to debug yours from here without any detail.

Comment: They will not give me any error but  will not finish executing and they will stuck

Comment: I think you should debug the code by yourself. This code above works properly and stores the information in csv file. Possible errors that comes to my mind: Maybe you don't have ```numpy``` installed (however if it was the case, you would get an error). Maybe you should just restart the IDE to make it work properly. Maybe you should try checking the website opened in Selenium if it works properly (works ok for me).

Comment: also not provide data in `data frame`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Could you mark this solution as answer if it was helpful?

Comment: my problem is not solve

Comment: can you provide me answer in `dataframe`

Comment: You can download the csv file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hg71EhMD_xEoD400I0L1tJRbuim51Xwh/view?usp=sharing). Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: why I am not getting `csv file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237525/discussion-between-muhteva-and-arslan-aziz).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
data = {
         'Details': lists_
        }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv('out.csv', index = 0)
```

you should write this outside the for loop that you've.

Comment: they show these error `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: @ArslanAziz :  That is not cause of my code which is for df, you have issue with your existing code especially with selenium.

Comment: when I run the code they print the data with any issue

Comment: I am using `lists_` from your code, are you sure you want to have `lists_` only in your df ?

Comment: yes I have only`lists_`in data frame as above you share me your code of dataframe

Comment: Stale element you get when you moved from current html to some other html and comes back at the original html.

Comment: is there any method to solve these issue

Comment: you try to solve  it??